# How can I start a "blinking light" sequence on a button press (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this simple code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.IN)

break_prog=False

def key_press(key):
   print("BREAK")
   global break_prog
   break_prog=True

GPIO.add_event_detect(21,GPIO.FALLING,callback=key_press,bouncetime=300)

for i in range(5):
    if break_prog:
       print("STOP THE LOOP")
       break
    else:
       print("GREEN")
       GPIO.output(2,True)
       GPIO.output(14,False)
       time.sleep(3)
       print("RED")
       GPIO.output(2,False)
       GPIO.output(14,True)   
       time.sleep(6)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

My goal is simply to make the lights blink 5 times (for loop).

That is working fine and I can stop it by pressing on the button.

But what I'd like to do is to start the sequence on button press.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this in a simple way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy to learn better way to achieve it , but tha's the way I have done it:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.IN)

run=False

def key_press(key):
   global run
   if run:
      print("run=0")
      run=False
   else:
      print("run=1")
      run = True

GPIO.add_event_detect(21,GPIO.FALLING,callback=key_press,bouncetime=300)

def seq():
       if(not run):
         print("stop")
         return
       print("GREEN")
       GPIO.output(2,True)
       GPIO.output(14,False)
       time.sleep(3)
       if(not run):
         print("stop")
         return
       print("RED")
       GPIO.output(2,False)
       GPIO.output(14,True)   
       time.sleep(6)

while True:
   if run:
      print("start")
      for i in range (5):
         if(run):
            seq()
      run=False


GPIO.cleanup()
```